# How can I make react router redirect to root after signup?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

I have crated a signup method that is creating a user and saves it on MongoDb. The backend is working fine, all good there. The user gets created but on the frontend it stays on the same signup page instead of redirecting to root.

```
async function authFunction (evt) {

    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            username: nameValue,
            email: emailValue,
            password: passwordValue
        }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(data.text); 
    console.log({ user: data });

}
```

In App.js I have created the routes I needed and added  but nothing happens.

```
<div className='App'>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
        <Route path='/tasks' component={TasksInitial} />
        <Route path='/auth' component={AuthPanel} />
        <Route path='/api/logout' component={Landing} />

        <Redirect to='/' />
    </Switch>
</div>
```

I want to make it redirect to root after signup.

Answer (score 0):

From the component where the `authFunction` function is called, you should pass a redirecting function and use it inside as a callback.

```
authFunction(evt, this.props.history.push);
```

and inside your function:

```
async function authFunction (evt, changeRoute) {
   ...
   if (response.ok) {
      changeRoute('/');
   }
}
```

Remember to wrap your component with `withRouter` hoc to have access to the `history` object.